# Weird datetime output from MomentJS

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, momentjs

I stumbled on this problem today and I cannot work out why is that. I'm creating two moment datetimes:

```
moment.utc('0001-01-01 00:00:00').add(63613382702000, 'ms').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.sss Z')
```

and

```
moment.utc('0001-01-01 00:00:00').add(63613382702999, 'ms').format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.sss Z')
```

they both produce `30/10/2016 00:05:02.022 +00:00` as a result but I would expect them to be different, what's causing them to be the very same timestamp?

Comment: They are different dates, I can't find the documentation on the format `sss`, did you mean `SSS`? As that seems to [give you the better format](https://jsfiddle.net/7x00s4b1/1/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the moment.js Documentation https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/ Milliseconds (Fractional Seconds) are formated with a capital S.

The correct format would be `'DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss.SSS'`.

https://plnkr.co/edit/cXHvjPBzotJAcrIhnDYY?p=preview

Comment: thank you very much.. it's a shame momentjs just fails so silently without giving a shit about it :-)

Comment: mh i dont think moment.js should fail or alert, its valid to create a format as u did.. you just repeated the seconds. try to add a char that is not supported, it should throw an exception